# Magento 2: Refresh Statistics Automatically On Page Load Or via Cron Job

Tags: magento2, cron, reports, crontab

When ever we see any Admin Report, Every time need to click & update "Refresh Statistics".

> For accurate reporting, be sure to refresh lifetime statistics
>   whenever you change the time zone. Last updated: Nov 21, 2016, 9:06:37
>   PM. To refresh last day's statistics, click here.

I would like to do it Automatically. So whenever data changed Statistics update Automatically.